# How this categorical variable have no reference value?

Tags: multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model

I'm reading the vignette for fixest

After fitting this model for trade between countries:

$E\left(Trade_{i,j,p,t}\right)=\exp\left(\gamma_{i}^{Exporter}+\gamma_{j}^{Importer}+\gamma_{p}^{Product}+\gamma_{t}^{Year}+\beta\times
\ln Distance_{ij}\right)$

where $\gamma$ are fixed effects, [we extract the fixed effects](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/fixest_walkthrough.html#extracting-the-fixed-effects-coefficients) and we discover that `Origin` has no reference value.

How is that possible?

I thought the model included the fixed effects as a one dummy variable per category.

Then you have to drop one of the variables, otherwise they would be perfectly multi-collinear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe because there's no separate "intercept" term here.

When the model contains an intercept term, dropping a level of a dummy variable is necessary, otherwise it's impossible for the model to distinguish the intercept from the dummy variable. It's *kind of* like collinearity, but specifically collinearity with the constant intercept term.

But in this case there's no separate intercept term in the model. So the fixed effects add up to act like a separate intercept term for each group.

Comment: Didn't realize there was no intercept. Thanks!